# Config.xml ignored in creation process

Tags: cordova

I am having a problem using the command line tool **cordova-cli**.

I have followed every step from the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/):

> $ cordova create ~/test com.test test

In this step I want to change the contents of the `www` folder:

1-Move the sample web page under a `src` folder. So the contents of the `www` are:

> ```
> --www/
> |-- config.xml
> |-- src/
> ```

2-Edit the config.xml with my data and change the `content` tag to point the correct path of the `index.html`:

```
<widget id="com.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Test</name>
  <description>
                Test
  </description>
  <author email="foo@bar.com" href="http://sample.com/">
              Foo Bar
  </author>
  <content src="src/index.html"/>
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />    
</widget>
```

With this file changed I continue with the general steps (from the root of the project):

Add iOS platform:

> $ cordova platform add ios

And then build the project:

> $ cordova build

Now, if I open the project under `test/platforms/ios/test` I see a config.xml with a default content as:

```
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
</widget>
```

Notice that `UIWebViewBounce` preference is correct, but the `content` tag is **incorrect**, as well as the `author` tag, `description` and `name`.

If then I run the app it fails, as it tries to open the `www/index.html` instead of `www/src/index.html`.

Am I doing something wrong?

**NOTE**

The contents of the `test/www` is copied correctly into `test/platforms/ios/www`.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, expect I'm trying to set the icon in the `www/config.xml` file.

Comment: Yes, I'm having both of these issues (content src and res icons). It's updating the version and app name on build, but basically ignoring everything else. I'm running it on Windows 8. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using OS X as well.

Answer (score 13):

This is not a real answer, but I opened two tickets in Cordova's JIRA regarding this problem [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4356) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4378).

Currently Cordova client does `not` support this features in the `config.xml`. You will need to modify the icons and splashscreens manually at this time as well the `content` tag in every platform project. Notice that you only have to do this once as Cordova maintain the `config.xml` changes and other resources as images.

Likely, a next version will include these features.

---

More info:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2606

---

UPDATE:

It seems that this issue has been solved in this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/pull/126). It will available in the next release of Cordova.

Comment: @LandonSchropp You're welcome. I think I'm going to be notified when the people of Cordova release an update with this (JIRA mechanism), so I´ll try to keep update this answer

Comment: Actually I opened a ticket for it too and got the same answer. It's confusing because they include a res folder in the www directory, which would lead one to believe it should work that way.

Answer (score 0):

The config.xml file is used, when you are using the PhoneGap Build service.

More information aubout the config.xml is found [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics)