# PhoneGap iOS App Icon

Tags: ios, cordova

So I'm trying to specify my custom iOS icons for my app in my config.xml file, using the guide at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

However, when I use the line of code they give you, the app fails to load, and throws an error in XCode;

```
2013-07-24 09:32:06.121 iLens[19852:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[CDVConfigParser parser:parseErrorOccurred:], /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/carlzeiss/phonegap-2.9.0/iLens/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVConfigParser.m:93

2013-07-24 09:32:06.121 iLens[19852:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'config.xml parse error line 38 col 40'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x173012 0x28eee7e 0x172e78 0x1564665 0x7a352 0x15aca08 0x58e02af 0x58fa745 0x590225a 0x59044e5 0x5903f07 0x15ac8fe 0x15ac890 0x15acb46 0x15acbfa 0x590d2 0x57ea0 0x57f6e 0x83749 0x48de1e 0x5802e 0x837ad 0x8326b 0x3ac157 0x3ac747 0x3ad94b 0x3becb5 0x3bfbeb 0x3b1698 0x3720df9 0x3720ad0 0xe8bf5 0xe8962 0x119bb6 0x118f44 0x118e1b 0x3ad17a 0x3aeffc 0x82f4c 0x82ea9)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

If I remove the **gap:platform="ios"** part, the app loads, but the icon doesn't change.

Does anyone have a working example of changing icons through the config.xml file please?

Note: I don't believe this is a duplicate of the question that has been linked to this question. My question is in regards to adding icons through the `config.xml` file, as you should be able to do as per the PhoneGap documents. However, it turns out that they didn't support this option at that time.

Comment: Not through the config.xml file.  In the end I've set the icons and splashscreens through XCode.  Would love to know if you find a fix though.

Comment: I started a bounty on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792787/config-xml-ignored-in-creation-process) and it seems to be getting a little more attention. It looks like the main issue is even though it's documented Cordova doesn't support the icon tag.

Comment: Please include sample from your config file. Obviously the error is due to improper xml. But it's hard to fix if we don't know what it looks like

Comment: @AlexReynolds it's down to PhoneGap / Cordova not supporting it yet (at time of issue), not improper XML

Answer (score -1):

Open Your project in Xcode and place App Icon it will work.

Comment: The issue / question was about setting the icon through the config.xml file