# Cordova build with Xcode SQLite plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to build cordova (phone gap 2.9) application on xcode. I followed the tutorial from http://vimeo.com/56673251 and generated the sencha app. I am able to use cordova builder and get the xcode project. But when i build my xcode project I get bunch of linker errors as follows:

```
"_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
      -[SQLitePlugin executeSqlWithDict:andArgs:] in SQLitePlugin.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[SQLitePlugin open:] in SQLitePlugin.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[SQLitePlugin executeSqlWithDict:andArgs:] in SQLitePlugin.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[SQLitePlugin executeSqlWithDict:andArgs:] in SQLitePlugin.o
  "_sqlite3_threadsafe", referenced from:
      -[SQLitePlugin open:] in SQLitePlugin.o
  "_sqlite3_total_changes", referenced from:
      -[SQLitePlugin executeSqlWithDict:andArgs:] in SQLitePlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **libsqlite** framework in order to use SQLitePlugin in your Xcode. To do that, click on your Project file --> Targets --> Build Phases --> Link Binary with Libraries --> Press + button and add `libsqlite3.dylib` or `libsqlite3.0.dylib`.

Now, after doing this, clean the project and run.. Should do..

Good luck!

Comment: Now when i try to run the project on simulator, I am hitting run time issue . I get the following error:    Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-08-22 09:22:50.286 Velocity_iphone[23166:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[CDVConfigParser parser:parseErrorOccurred:], /Users/mupdivya/Documents/Apps/velocity-iphone/build/Velocity_iphone/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVConfigParser.m:93
2013-08-22 09:22:50.287 Velocity_iphone[23166:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'config.xml parse error line 116 col 1'     Any help on this will be great

Comment: I guess it's something to do with Config.xml.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828920/phonegap-ios-app-icon   Could this help you?

Comment: Did you fix the issue?